# Updating PublishVersion/MinimumRequiredVersion in .csproj

Tags: svn, msbuild, oneclick

This is for a OneClick program.

Initially, I am getting the revision number from subwcrev and populating the assemblyinfo.cs.

I created a pre-build event with this logic. I am able to see the new revision in the assembly information pop-up in the properties dialog.

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>subwcrev $(ProjectDir) "$(ProjectDir)Build\AssemblyInfo.cs.txt"  "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" -f</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I am trying to sync the MinimumRequiredVersion and PublishVersion so they match the assembly information.

I created a Target for this:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="TargetAssemblyIdentity" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishVersion>%(TargetAssemblyIdentity.Version)</PublishVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MinimumRequiredVersion>%(TargetAssemblyIdentity.Version)</MinimumRequiredVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

This does not update the PublishVersion or MinimumRequiredVersion, but it does allow me to show a message with it if I use the 'Message' tag.

This is the values I am trying to update.
[image]

Any ideas what I am missing to get this done when I build the project.

Comment: Is this for a ClickOnce application? Where did you find `PublishVersion` in Microsoft's documentation?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes sorry. I’ll add it to the question.

Comment: I don't think `PublishVersion` is an MSBuild property for ClickOnce. There is an `ApplicationVersion` property which is used for the `Version` in the application manifest.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I looked at the .csproj and thats the tag that shows up,
I am looking to match the assembly verison publish version and minimumrequiredversion

Comment: Is the .csproj a legacy style project or an SDK style project? Can you share the`PropertyGroup` from the .csproj file that defines a `PublishVersion` property? BTW the UI property page won't reflect the version change.

Comment: It would be legacy .csproj. It does update the UI for the AssemblyVersion, so is that just not an option for Publishing?

Comment: There is no UI for the `AssemblyVersion` and your `PreBuildEvent` property is a command to update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: Documentation for the [ClickOnce Publish properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-dotnet-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#publish-properties) shows `ApplicationVersion` and `ApplicationRevision` and explains how those properties are used for the manifest file.